# Confusion Matrix accuracy assessment non equal length user and producer datasets

Tags: python, pandas, classification, confusion-matrix

I am trying to perform the following classification assessment:[image]

My issue is that my classified has over 3000000 classified pixels and my training dataset only has around 30-40 (10-15 for each class that could be stated).

My datasets both have the same layout as follow:

> Training row example = [[230,40,120,2]] With the first three values
>   being the pixel color bands (BGR) and the final being the stated
>   output class (Can we 1-3).

I am reading in the training data as a csv file and converting to a pandas dataframe.

Question: Is it possible to use this method even though I have different number of predicted and actual data values in the two datasets? And if so not sure what lines 9 through 13 are used for.

Code:

```
b,g,r = cv2.split(img)
# Pandas dataset
dataSet = pd.DataFrame({'bBnad':b.flat[:],'gBnad':g.flat[:],'rBnad':r.flat[:]})
dataSet['class'] = X_clustered
training = pd.read_csv("/Users/chrisradford/Documents/School/Masters/RA/Classifier/Python/Training.csv")
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @mad_ updated with the question thanks for the catch

Comment: First of all, avoid posting images. Line 9-13 is segregating your features and target values. and test_size will be a param used to split the values in test and training datasets.